# AHK export txt to pdf

Tags: autohotkey

In notepad++ I want a way, using AHK, to quickly export it using pandoc from a txt to a pdf.

I'm halfway though the code. It does not work. What I want to do is

1. Go to Edit>Copy To Clipboard>Current File path to Clipboard
2. Open command line
3. Write "pandoc -o ^v Del3 pdf space ^v enter"

   ```
   ^!e::
   Send, {Alt Down}e{Alt Up}
   Sleep, 100
   Send, {Down 8} 
   Sleep, 300
   Send, {Enter 2}
   Run, cmd.exe
   Sleep, 500
   Send, pandoc -o
   Send, {Ctrl Down}v{Ctrl Up}
   ```

What do I do wrong? And how is the correct script?

EDIT:

Down 8 and Enter 2 puts the file path of my TXT to the clipboard. The thing I want to write in the command line is not

> pandoc -o "%Clipboard%"

but rather

> pandoc -o pathToFile.pdf pathToFile.txt

where *pathToFile.txt* is what I have in the clipboard. (So I need to put DEL3 PDF SPACE PASTE ENTER). How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Try running Pandoc directly from the Run command, passing the clipboard as the param

```
Run, pandoc -o "%Clipboard%"
```

In regards to your edit:

```
; Remove file-ending
fileNamePath := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "\..*$", "")

; Run command
Run, pandoc -o "%fileNamePath%.pdf" "%Clipboard%"
```

Comment: I need it to do a little bit more, see the edit.

Comment: @user1603548 Added a possible solution in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first part of your code, you may also benefit from using WinMenuSelectItem for better speed/reliability in selecting the menu item without having to send keystrokes and wait for the menu to respond.

This will work for most menus such as those in Notepad++ (but not for Microsoft Ribbon applications).

Incorporating code snippets above into an example...

```
^!e::
lastClip := clipboardAll ; save the clipboard contents so they don't get overwritten
clipboard := ""

WinMenuSelectItem, A,,Edit,Copy to Clipboard,Current Full File path to Clipboard     ; A = Active Window... make sure menu descriptions match exactly

clipWait, 1   ; wait for new clipboard contents max 1 second
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, The attempt to copy failed
    clipboard := lastClip
    return
}

; Remove file-ending
fileNamePath := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "\..*$", "")

; Run command
Run, pandoc -o "%fileNamePath%.pdf" "%Clipboard%"

clipboard := lastClip     ; restore clipboard to previous contents    

return
```

In the code above 'A' means active window.  I didn't actually try and test this code... just make sure the menu item names match exactly what you would like to select.